# Best way to avoid db calls in for loop

Tags: python, mysql, for-loop, stored-procedures, large-data

On the main page, I have a list of items that populate in the middle panel in 8 columns(master data of the item) and on selecting a particular row/item more details about that item is shown on the right side panel.
Currently I'm trying to get the list of items and their details in a single call. But for this I have to run a for loop and hit the db 2-3 times to get the details. And over a period when number of items increase, the time it takes to load the main page increases as well.

I'm thinking of changing the design and only when the user clicks on the item I make another call to get the details which should be much faster.

But I would like to know if there is a way to make the first approach much faster.

I'm using python for the back end and mysql for the db.

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43377845/how-to-avoid-calling-db-queries-inside-of-loops-for-child-data) can help

Comment: show us your code or at least a [mre] that shows what you expect

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.